# Package name changing and keeping existing reviews and downloads

Tags: android

Hi i have a company app with few thousand downloads done by a developer who is not working with me anymore. I didn't knew much about these android package name stuff and he has used his name in my app package name with app name. 
eg.. com.micheal.myapp
Now he is not giving me source code too.

So is there anyway to upload a new package like com.myapp.appname and keep all those downloads and reviews?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way until you don't get previous application source code and application key store.

if you upload a new package then it'll be considered as a new application.

Comment: If i get his source code and key then can i change the package name and keep all my reviews and downloads and in the same time change the package name?

If i get his source code can i change package name com.micheal.myapp to com.mycompany.myapp and keep all the reviews and downloads?

Comment: @Monark as mentioned if you upload a new package it'll be considered as a new application and all downloads and reviews will be gone. See this for detail  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html